# how to figure out byte size of string in c

Tags: c, sockets

I have a string say

```
    char resp_buf[20000];

    sprintf(resp_buf,"HTTP/1.0 404 File not Found.\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\\
n\r\n<html><body><h2>Error 404: The file your have requested does not exist.</h2\
></body></html>");
```

So after this when later I call the send-->

```
send(fd,resp_buf,strlen(a),0);
```

The data does get sent but the server crashes and give segmentation fault.

How can I find its size in bytes so that I can use it in send() for socket programming. I'm getting a whole load of segmentation errors. I have tried strlen(a) and sizeof(a), but again the both give

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: `strlen(a)` or `sizeof(a)` should work in this case. Please show your code.

Comment: And let us know what compiler/system etc -- 'strlen(a)' should work.

Comment: I just added the code and flow of what I'm doing.

Comment: Please, if you're getting a segfault, you have to show us the line of code where the fault is and the stacktrace. It's there on the screen in front of you, so why should you make us guess?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localised.

Comment: Sorry I cant see the stacktrace, I'm using a ubuntu terminal and gcc compiler!

Comment: First, you should use `char resp_buf[20000] = {0};` which initializes the buffer with `0`. Otherwise it might crash - no surprises. And I think `a` is same as `resp_buf` - isn't it?. Try this.

Comment: Well have you tried debugging your code yourself (in gdb) before posting the question?

Comment: since it is server that crashes you must be having server logs. they may help!

Comment: @MohitArora, your `send` uses `strlen(a)`. Did you mean `strlen(resp_buf)`? And you need to shore more code than that. The segfault is probably not occurring on the couple of lines you show.

Comment: @ManojAwasthi I believe `sprintf` always zero terminates the string.

Comment: @mbratch He mentioned that it is server that crashes not the client. Mohit, you have to share server logs atleast for any help.

Comment: @ManojAwasthi indeed, good catch. We need to see server side receiver code and/or logs.

Comment: @mrbratch thanks for letting me check deep into the man page. it indeed adds a NUL terminator. thanks!!

Comment: When I do a perror(resp_buf), it does output the string and then appends : No file od directory... No logging I just created a very simple server... very near a deadline no time to format and post code! Sorry guys and thansk for all the help

Comment: What is `a`?  What does it contain?  Are you sure you didn't mean to type `send( fd, resp_buf, strlen( resp_buf ), 0);`?

Comment: I resolved it buddy, thanks y'all for you inputs; I was just getting a bit restless so I posted here. Sorry about that!

Comment: Back to your lives, citizens... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int sprintf(char * restrict str, const char * restrict format, ...);
```

returns the amount of bytes printed as return value, you may want to try to use that.

Alternatively there is always

```
size_t strlen(const char *s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to allocate 20000 bytes on the stack. Firstly, that may be the cause of the crash. You shouldn't even be attempting that, and I'm not going to tell you a better way to allocate buffers, because the whole approach is wrong, so I'd just be helping you to get the wrong idea to limpingly work.

@mbratch is utterly wrong about sizeof(). You have no way to know that the result string is always exactly sizeof(resp_buf) bytes long a priori, and in fact, the code you posted makes a string that's nowhere near that long. So this would write some data and a lot of garbage, which is very likely not what you want.

What happens when (later on, perhaps in response to a request from Marketing) this error HTML gets modified?  Are you planning to recompile your program every time they change their mind about the copy? That's not my idea of fun. Please Google for 'open coding' aka 'hard coding' and 'anti patterns'.

You shouldn't be using the printf family of functions when the first arg is not a format string wholly under your control, else you risk format string vulnerabilities. Google for that too. Crackers love people like you. In your case it's a constant string, not a format string.

You probably want something more like using fdopen to convert your fd into a FILE *, followed by use of fputs, with the data coming from a file. But more likely you really want to be using PHP or a CMS or something.

I think you should be seriously asking yourself why you are trying to write the world's crappiest web server with only a tiny amount of C knowledge. Apache is very good at serving files to the Web.

You've failed to tell us what you're trying to achieve, thus preventing us from helping you to avoid that.

I would vote this question down even more than already, if I could.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using valgrind. It helps you find the memory leaks and associated behavior.

http://valgrind.org/